# How to close the thread after @Scheduled execution (Spring boot)

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, hibernate, scheduled-tasks

I have a project which executes multiple scheduled method at start up.
I remarked that after scheduled methods are executed, the opened threads do not close, but remain in a 'parking' state.

[image]

Is this a normal behavior ?
Aren't the threads suppose to close after method is executed ? (Because keeping multiple threads open just slows down the application and consumes more RAM.)

Here are my code configurations:

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "scheduling.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class SchedulingConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {
}
```

Here is an example of method called in service:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 4 * * *")
protected void updateExchangeRates() {
    if (enablePostConstruct) {
        countryService.updateCountryExchangeRates();
    }
}
```

I would like to run the scheduled methods asynchronously, with a max thread pool consumed between 10-15 threads. And after execution, the thread to close and reopen in case it got to the point when it needs to be executed again.

Can you guide me please how this can be achieved ?
I tried to implement **SchedulingConfigurer** and perform executorService.shutdown(), but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a method annotated with @PreDestroy to invoke executorService.shutdown(). I wouldn't bother about the Parking State, you probably want those threads to be ready for the next invocation, so not really harmful that they are parked.
Nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: so the opened scheduling threads will still be available for other processes, correct ? I wonder, why spring does not close them at all after execution. 
Is there a recommendation for scheduled pool ? For example in case I have 30 scheduled methods which executes in various time, it will be ok to set a pool size of 5-10, isn't it ? I just don't see a point of keeping the threads opened if they are not used.

Comment: Think of the pool as a "reserve" of threads so they are readily available and reusable so you save the significant Thread instantiation cost. But having those threads in the pool doesn't mean they are taking your CPU cores/threads 100% of the time, they will take close to 0% when they are parked/sleep/ready and only use CPU on active state. The threads in the pool won't be available to other processes and will count towards the max number of threads your OS can handle (in the order or thousands). 5-10 would be ok or not depending on the frequency and length of the execution.Measure concurrency